# How to disable WordPress trackbacks?

Tags: spam, pingbacks

I have high Google Page Rank, and as a result of that, lots of spammers make trackbacks. Every day I have to delete them.

Will those trackbacks negatively affect my site's SEO?  How can I disable all trackbacks on my site?

I have run the following code in my MySQL admin and using the WordPress Manage DB plugin, but it shows me an error.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post';

UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page';
```

Comment: I think you can solve this problem by reading the answer [to this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/is-there-a-way-to-completely-turn-off-pingbacks-trackbacks). If it still doesn't work for you, then let us know.

Comment: You never said which error. That's pretty important when asking a Question.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved using the <kbd>Bulk Edit</kbd> WordPress functionality.

> [image: bulk edit]

and

> [image: editing bulk edit]

Change the number of items to be shown in <kbd>Screen Options</kbd>, so you can select all posts/pages at once.

Two things worth noting in the [Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31943/12615) pointed by @BartKarp:

- > There is the option to turn off trackbacks/pingbacks under `Settings > Discussion`.
- it has a link to a [plugin](https://gist.github.com/1309433) by @chrisguitarguy. If you want to implement total blockage of trackbacks, use *chris'*.

Comment: Thank you so much brasofilo. But I have more than 500 posts. Are there any quick method?

Comment: Well, writing a custom routine to get all posts, iterate through them and update the info. But the time involved in writing, testing and finally doing it, would be greater than going through the interface. Change the `Screen Options` to show 50 or 100 posts at a time, and it will be a breeze. I don't recommend setting a greater value as it'd be too much overload to the server. Surely, you can find the correct SQL query and go through PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I don't see __Pings__ in __Bulk Edit__ now, only __Comments__ :(

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Query**

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_type`="trackback"
```

Run Query from this plugin: [wp-dbmanager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/)