# Comments from other blogs are getting added to my blog?

Tags: comments

Today I started receiving a ton of requests to moderate comments on my blog, but when I looked at the comments they are clearly from multiple other people's blogs. What could be the cause of this and what do I do about this?

Comment: They are called 'spammers' and the general consensus is to avoid them.

Comment: @Nick Chapman you can disable trackback/pingback. Go and have a look at this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/is-there-a-way-to-completely-turn-off-pingbacks-trackbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Those are pingback or trackbacks.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Managing_Comments) They are mechanisms by which blogs alert each other about cross-linking or references to other posts.

Pingbacks and trackbacks are common from SPAM or scrapper sites so you do want to take a look and make sure you are not approving comments from disreputable sources but in general, these are normal and can be useful.

The pingback/trackback functionality has been built into WordPress for as long as I can remember. Your site probably sends similar "comments" to other blogs.

Comment: But the thing is, the comments don't make any mention of my site.

Comment: Just kidding, definitely spam

Comment: @NickChapman : What does that mean?

Comment: it means that I checked out the comments further and they were definitely pingbacks from spammers